# Encoding multiple values to a QR code so that they can be used in excel - c# or java

Tags: java, c#, excel, qr-code

I am trying to use QR codes for data transfer for competitions so that when a decoder camera decodes the QR code, it will be able to display in excel.  I do not have any code for this at the moment because I have not found anything.  Please help.  My team and I are planning on using either java or c# for the task, depending on which one we find can complete the task we need to be completed so either one is acceptable.  Also if this question is hard to follow, please say so and i can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Anyone there that can help?

Comment: Wait, so you want a Java/C# code to decode QR codes and put the result in an Excel file?